# Retrieve XElements from XML without Removing them from XDcoument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

I've been working on retrieving few XML nodes from an XML string. My requirement is to retrieve the XML nodes that do not match the list items. I was able to remove the ChildNodes from XML but couldn't able to find a solution retrieve the childNode that do not match List items.

Below is my Class

```
    public class MovieDetails 
        {
            public string MovieName { get; set; }
            public string MovieId { get; set; }
            public string MovieGenre { get; set; }
        }

   public class AdditionalInformation {

         public string MovieInformation {get;set;}
   }
```

MyXml:

```
<MovieContent>
  <MovieDetails>
      <MovieName>Movie_Name_1</MovieName>
      <MovieId>MovieId_1</MovieId>
      <MovieGenre>MovieGenre_3</MovieGenre>
      <AdditionalInformation>HAHAHHAHA</AdditionalInformation>
  </MovieDetails>
  <MovieDetails>
      <MovieName>Movie_Name_2</MovieName>
      <MovieId>MovieId_2</MovieId>
      <MovieGenre>MovieGenre_3</MovieGenre> 
      <AdditionalInformation>FOOOO</AdditionalInformation>
  </MovieDetails>
  <MovieDetails>
      <MovieName>Movie_Name_3</MovieName>
      <MovieId>MovieId_3</MovieId>
      <MovieGenre>MovieGenre_3</MovieGenre> 
      <AdditionalInformation></AdditionalInformation>
  </MovieDetails>
</MovieContent>
```

I tried using a Linq but couldn't get my desired result.

```
var properties = new HashSet<string> { "MovieName", "MovieId", "MovieGenre" };
var Descendants = testDoc.Descendants("MovieDetailsMovieDetails");
var infoList    =  Descendants.Elements()
                             .Where(e => properties.Contains(e.Name.LocalName));
```

Can anyone please help out in achieving the below resultant xml without using Remove()

Resultant XML:

```
    <MovieContent>
      <MovieDetails>
           <AdditionalInformation>HAHAHHAHA</AdditionalInformation>
      </MovieDetails>
      <MovieDetails>
            <AdditionalInformation>FOOOO</AdditionalInformation>
      </MovieDetails>
      <MovieDetails>
            <AdditionalInformation></AdditionalInformation>
      </MovieDetails>
    </MovieContent>
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - You could create a new Xml root like :

```
XDocument result = XDocument.Parse("<MovieContent></MovieContent>");
```

2 - Get tags that not exit in `properties` list, like:

```
var elements = testDoc
    .Descendants("MovieDetails")
    .Elements().Where(e => !properties.Contains(e.Name.LocalName));
```

3 - add `elements` to the `result` Root, like:

```
foreach (var item in elements)
{
    result.Root.Add(new XElement("MovieDetails", new XElement(item)));
}
```

**All code**

```
var properties = new HashSet<string> { "MovieName", "MovieId", "MovieGenre" };

var elements = testDoc
    .Descendants("MovieDetails")
    .Elements().Where(e => !properties.Contains(e.Name.LocalName));

XDocument result = XDocument.Parse("<MovieContent></MovieContent>");

foreach (var item in elements)
{
    result.Root.Add(new XElement("MovieDetails", new XElement(item)));
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Result**

```
<MovieContent>
  <MovieDetails>
    <AdditionalInformation>HAHAHHAHA</AdditionalInformation>
  </MovieDetails>
  <MovieDetails>
    <AdditionalInformation>FOOOO</AdditionalInformation>
  </MovieDetails>
  <MovieDetails>
    <AdditionalInformation></AdditionalInformation>
  </MovieDetails>
</MovieContent>
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use IEquable :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<MovieDetails> details = doc.Descendants("MovieDetails").Select(x => new MovieDetails()
            {
                MovieName = (string)x.Element("MovieName"),
                MovieId = (string)x.Element("MovieId"),
                MovieGenre = (string)x.Element("MovieGenre")
            }).ToList();

            MovieDetails properties = new MovieDetails() { MovieName = "Movie_Name_1", MovieId = "MovieId_1", MovieGenre = "MovieGenre_3" };

            List<MovieDetails> newDetails = details.Where(x => !x.Equals(properties)).ToList();

        }

    }
    public class MovieDetails :  IEquatable<MovieDetails>
    {
        public string MovieName { get; set; }
        public string MovieId { get; set; }
        public string MovieGenre { get; set; }

        public Boolean Equals(MovieDetails other)
        {
            MovieDetails detail = other as MovieDetails;

            return  (this.MovieName == other.MovieName) && (this.MovieId == detail.MovieId) && (this.MovieGenre == detail.MovieGenre);
        }
    }
}
```